# How to air gap the dependencies in Sonatype nexus 3?

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I have 2 nexus, one with no internet. Currently, I am migrating the dependencies from the nexus with internet to the nexus without internet by copying the "Blob" folder and "Component" folder in "Sonatype-work" directory like most website suggested.

As time past, the size of "blob" increases and it makes transferring slow.

Would like to ask if there is a way to just migrate the NEWLY added dependencies?